# What are the performance impications of utf8_bin vs utf8_general_ci collations in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I am working on a database, where the collation for all text fields seems to be utf8_general_ci.  There are cases where primary and foreign keys are collated utf8_general_ci (such as a session_id ).  Does it degrade performance to use a case-insenstive collation on columns where binary comparisons are fine?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course it's going to be slower to do more work. Whether the difference is significant to your application is another question.